# Custom loss function produces extremely low loss value with Keras 2.1.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm working with a dataset of numerical and categorical values (time series). This is a sample of the variables:
`A B C_1 C_2 D_1 D_2 D_3`
First two are numerical variables, C and D are categorical variables with a onehot representation.

Below my custom loss function. I use partial in order to pass more than two parameters to the function:

```
def mixed_num_cat_loss_backend(y_true, y_pred, signals_splits):
    if isinstance(y_true, np.ndarray):
        y_true = keras.backend.variable( y_true )
    if isinstance(y_pred, np.ndarray):
        y_pred = keras.backend.variable( y_pred )

    y_true_mse = y_true[:,:signals_splits[0]] 
    y_pred_mse = y_pred[:,:signals_splits[0]]
    mse_loss_v = keras.backend.square(y_true_mse-y_pred_mse)

    categ_loss_v = [ keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(
                             y_pred[:,signals_splits[i-1]:signals_splits[i]], #keras.backend.softmax(y_pred[:,signals_splits[i-1]:signals_splits[i]]), 
                             y_true[:,signals_splits[i-1]:signals_splits[i]], 
                         from_logits=False) # force keras to normalize
                    for i in range(1,len(signals_splits)) ]

    losses_v = keras.backend.concatenate( [mse_loss_v, keras.backend.stack(categ_loss_v,1)], 1)

    return losses_v
```

After one epoch I have an extremely low loss value:

```
Epoch 1/100
76s - loss: 0.1040 - acc: 0.1781 - val_loss: 0.0016 - val_acc: 0.1330  
Epoch 2/100  
75s - loss: 9.2523e-04 - acc: 0.1788 - val_loss: 8.7442e-04 - val_acc: 0.1330
```

**The point is that I don't have this problem when I use Keras 2.0.4.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of cross-entropy backend methods has changed since Keras 2.0.7. According to the [release note](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases),

> The backend methods `categorical_crossentropy`,
>   `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, `binary_crossentropy` had the order of
>   their positional arguments (`y_true`, `y_pred`) inverted. This change does
>   not affect the `losses` API. This change was done to achieve API
>   consistency between the `losses` API and the backend API.

So you should switch the place of `y_true` and `y_pred` when calling `categorical_crossentropy` in newer versions of Keras.